How can I turn this combine().all () into a synchronous chain due a Hibernate Reactive limitation?
I'm using Quarkus version 3.13.0 and also using Hibernate Reactive.
I have created the code below using Mutiny's Uni.combine() to query two entities and then persist a third entity (Join Table) using both results.
I was bitten by this Hibernate limitation that prevents us to use the same session in parallel executions.
I'm new to Mutiny, so I would like a help to turn this code into a synchronous chain that would fix the error I'm getting, because I couldn't find any other method other than combine() that provides a BiFunction.
@POST
@Path("{userId}/teams/{businessUnitId}")
public Uni<RestResponse<UserDto>> assignToTeam(Long userId, Long businessUnitId, @RestQuery String pRole) {
    if (businessUnitId == null || userId == null) {
        throw new WebApplicationException(MSG_INVALID_PAYLOAD, 422);
    }

    return Uni.combine()
            .all()
            .unis(Panache.withTransaction(() -> userRepo.findById(userId)
                    .onItem()
                    .ifNull()
                    .failWith(new WebApplicationException(MSG_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND, NOT_FOUND))),
                    Panache.withTransaction(() -> businessUnitRepo.findById(businessUnitId)
                            .onItem()
                            .ifNull()
                            .failWith(new WebApplicationException(MSG_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND, NOT_FOUND))))
            .with((user, bunit) -> {
                BusinessUnitsUsers buu = new BusinessUnitsUsersBuilder().parentEntity(bunit)
                        .childEntity(user)
                        .role(pRole)
                        .build();
                return user.assingToTeam(buu);
            })
            .chain(r -> Panache.withTransaction(() -> userRepo.persist(r))
                    .map(user -> RestResponse.ok(userMapper.toDto(user, usersBusinessUnitContext))));
}

This is the error I get:
2024-08-06 13:20:30,632 ERROR [http-problem] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-1) status=500, title="Internal Server Error": io.smallrye.mutiny.CompositeException: Multiple exceptions caught:
        [Exception 0] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session/EntityManager is closed
        [Exception 1] io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable: Transaction already complete
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniOnFailure.lambda$call$3(UniOnFailure.java:108)


This should work:
@POST
@Path("{userId}/teams/{businessUnitId}")
public Uni<RestResponse<UserDto>> assignToTeam(Long userId, Long businessUnitId, @RestQuery String pRole) {
    if (businessUnitId == null || userId == null) {
        throw new WebApplicationException(MSG_INVALID_PAYLOAD, 422);
    }

    return Panache
        .withTransaction(() -> userRepo
                    .findById(userId)
                    .onItem().ifNull().failWith(new WebApplicationException(MSG_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND, NOT_FOUND))
        )
        .chain( user -> Panache
            .withTransaction(() -> businessUnitRepo
                .findById(businessUnitId)
                .onItem().ifNull().failWith(new WebApplicationException(MSG_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND, NOT_FOUND))
            )
            .chain( bunit -> {
                BusinessUnitsUsers buu = new BusinessUnitsUsersBuilder()
                        .parentEntity(bunit)
                        .childEntity(user)
                        .role(pRole)
                        .build();
                return user.assingToTeam(buu);
            } )
            .chain(r -> Panache
                .withTransaction(() -> userRepo.persist(r) )
                .map(user -> RestResponse.ok(userMapper.toDto(user, usersBusinessUnitContext)))
            );
        )
}


When you combine Unis it is possible to limit the number of concurrent upstream subscription. By setting the concurrency to 1, the upstream Unis will execute sequentially, which avoids the Hibernate-related problems. Unfortunately, this approach means you loose type information about the elements, so you need to recreate it in the combinator function.
Therefore your code should work like this:
@POST
@Path("{userId}/teams/{businessUnitId}")
public Uni<RestResponse<UserDto>> assignToTeam(Long userId, Long businessUnitId, @RestQuery String pRole) {
    if (businessUnitId == null || userId == null) {
        throw new WebApplicationException(MSG_INVALID_PAYLOAD, 422);
    }

    return Uni.combine()
            .all()
            .unis(
              Panache.withTransaction(() -> userRepo.findById(userId)
                    .onItem()
                    .ifNull()
                    .failWith(new WebApplicationException(MSG_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND, NOT_FOUND))),
              Panache.withTransaction(() -> businessUnitRepo.findById(businessUnitId)
                    .onItem()
                    .ifNull()
                    .failWith(new WebApplicationException(MSG_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND, NOT_FOUND)))
            )
            .usingConcurrencyOf(1)   // <- Limit concurrency to 1 to avoid Hibernate-related problems
            .with(results -> {
                BusinessUnitsUsers buu = new BusinessUnitsUsersBuilder().parentEntity((BusinessUnit) results.get(1))
                        .childEntity((User) results.get(0))
                        .role(pRole)
                        .build();
                return user.assingToTeam(buu);
            })
            .chain(r -> Panache.withTransaction(() -> userRepo.persist(r))
                    .map(user -> RestResponse.ok(userMapper.toDto(user, usersBusinessUnitContext))));
}

